# How to determine the convergence or divergence of this series using the Ratio Test?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, factorial

[image]

After applying the Ratio Test we can cancel most terms in the factorials. But what to do with the denominator in the original series? Can it be considered as a factorial?

Also, I think we can use the divergence test in this series, as I think the limit will approach $\infty$ as $n$ approaches $\infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you have indeed$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(2n)!}{3\times5\times\cdots\times(2n+1)}=\infty,$$but you have to prove it.

On the other hand,$$\frac{\frac{(2(n+1))!}{3\times5\times\cdots\times(2n+3)}}{\frac{(2n)!}{3\times5\times\cdots\times(2n+1)}}=\frac{(2n+1)(2n+2)}{2n+3}$$and, since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(2n+1)(2n+2)}{2n+3}$ diverges indeed by the ratio test.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Try simplifying: $$\frac{(3)(5)(7)\dotsb(2n+1)}{(3)(5)(7)\dotsb(2(n+1)+1)} =\ ?$$